# Error with a column name I don't have when displaying activity in my Redmine plugin

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, android-activity, plugins, redmine

I'm currently developping a redmine plugin, and I'd like to have the actions made with the plugin displayed in the activity stream and I'd also like to be able to search among the objects created by my plugin.
I followed Alex Bevilacque's tutorial, very carefully. If you have any clue on what I am doing wrong, it would be great!

Everything is about "prestations".

I've got this to migrate my db:

```
class CreatePrestations < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :prestations do |t|
      t.column :nom, :string, :null => false
      t.column :description, :text
      t.column :project_id, :int, :default => 0
      t.column :author_id, :int, :default => 0, :null => false
      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

And this model:

```
class Prestation < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :project
  validates_presence_of :nom

  acts_as_searchable :columns => [ "#{table_name}.nom", "#{table_name}.description"],
                     :scope => preload(:project),
                     :date_column => "created_at"

  acts_as_event :title => Proc.new { |o| "#{l(:label_title_prestation)} ##{o.id} - #{o.nom}"},
                :description => :description,
                :datetime => :updated_at,
                :type => Proc.new { |o| 'prestation-' + (o.new_status ? 'add' : 'edit') },
                :url => Proc.new { |o| {:controller => 'prestations', :action => 'show', :id => o.id, :project_id => o.project} }

  acts_as_activity_provider :scope => preload(:project),
                            :author_key => :author_id,
                            :type => 'prestations',
                            :timestamp => :updated_at,
                            :permission => :activity_presta

end
```

And this at the very beginning of my init.rb:

```
Rails.configuration.to_prepare do
  Redmine::Activity.register :prestations
  Redmine::Search.available_search_types << 'prestations'
end
```

When I click on "search", I can search among every normal redmine fields, but not my "prestations", and when I look at the activity stream, I've got this:

```
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid (SQLite3::SQLException: no such column: projects.id: SELECT "prestations".* FROM "prestations" WHERE (updated_at BETWEEN '2016-05-20' AND '2016-06-19') AND (((projects.id = 1 OR (projects.lft > 1 AND projects.rgt < 2))) AND (projects.status = 1))):
  lib/plugins/acts_as_activity_provider/lib/acts_as_activity_provider.rb:81:in `find_events'
  lib/redmine/activity/fetcher.rb:91:in `block (2 levels) in events'
  lib/redmine/activity/fetcher.rb:90:in `each'
  lib/redmine/activity/fetcher.rb:90:in `block in events'
  lib/redmine/activity/fetcher.rb:89:in `each'
  lib/redmine/activity/fetcher.rb:89:in `events'
  app/controllers/activities_controller.rb:56:in `index'
  lib/redmine/sudo_mode.rb:63:in `sudo_mode'
```

I reseted the database to start a new redmine from scratch, I reloaded the server and changed the token, up to no avail.

I really don't understand why
1) I can't even get the possibility to search among my "prestations" (just having the checkbox would be great)
2) Rails tries to look for "projects.id" which I didn't ask for

Thanks a lot in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found something in projects.rb:

```
  def project_condition(with_subprojects)
    cond = "#{Project.table_name}.id = #{id}"
    cond = "(#{cond} OR (#{Project.table_name}.lft > #{lft} AND #{Project.table_name}.rgt < #{rgt}))" if with_subprojects
    cond
  end
```

I think even though Redmine Knownledgebase tutorial is a good introduction, it's really full of bas examples if you want to make your own plugin.